# Initialize a variable with a DOM element: is the "window.onload" best for it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6

What's, or where is, the safet way to initialize a variable that points to a DOM element, let's say, a div or image?

```
let myImg;

window.onload (e) => {
  myImg = document.getElementById("my_img_1");
}

function doSomething(a, b, c) {
  //using myImg
}
```

Are there any issues with this code? Is this a proper way to initialize a DOM variable?

Comment: You aren't "initializing" a DOM element, you're getting a reference to it. You can safely use `getElementById` provided the element exists in the DOM - if the element is in the server-rendered HTML then the "best" event to use is `DOMContentLoaded` which ocurrs before `window`'s `load` event. You can also safely use it in a `defer`'d `<script>` element (as a deferred script runs _immediately before_ the `DOMContentLoaded` event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` event (what you're currently using) usually isn't a great choice because it happens **really** late, waiting until all resources (including images, etc.) are loaded. Sometimes you want that, but not often.

You have lots of options. Here's a list in my personal order of preference:

1. Use `type="module"` on your `script` tag so your JavaScript code is a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), not a global script. Modules (both inline and via `src`) are automatically deferred (see the next item). (They also have other benefits: the code in them isn't at global scope, so they're nicely contained; they're automatically in strict mode; they can load other modules via `import`.) This [works in](https://caniuse.com/es6-module) all modern browsers (so, not with IE11).
2. Use the [`defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) on your `script` tag. That tells the browser to download and parse the code, but not to *run* it until it's done parsing the HTML. Only works with `src`, though, not inline. This [works in](https://caniuse.com/script-defer) all modern browsers and also IE10+.
3. Put the `script` at the end of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. It won't be run until all the HTML above it has been parsed and put in the DOM. This has *always* worked.
4. Use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event. This [works in](https://caniuse.com/domcontentloaded) anything even *vaguely* modern, including IE9+.
5. Use the `load` event (what you're currently using; just including it on the list for completeness). This has worked basically forever.

So for example:

```html
<script type="module" src="your-code.js"></script>
```

`your-code.js`:

```js
const myImg = document.getElementById("my_img_1");

function doSomething(a, b, c) {
    //using myImg
}
```

Inline example just to demonstrate the deferring:

```html
<script type="module">
const myImg = document.getElementById("my_img_1");

function doSomething(a, b, c) {
    myImg.style.border = "2px solid yellow";
}

doSomething();
</script>
<img id="my_img_1" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDABQODxIPDRQSEBIXFRQYHjIhHhwcHj0sLiQySUBMS0dA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">
```

Note that the `script` is above the `img`, but it still works — because the script execution is deferred.

Comment: @Ojag - LOL, I **literally** just edited to say that that's what you're currently using. :-) I should have said that initially.